# dynamic image loading google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have a newbie question about running JavaScript on my website, and how images load.

Essentially, I developed a page which will generate a simple, on-screen invoice for a small business owner.  The owner can go to the page, click a button, and they are asked for a variety of inputs to populate the invoice.  They're asked to enter an image for their logo, a list of work they did (& what they charged), contact information at the bottom, and more.

It's primitive and I know there's many services out there that do this professionally, but I own a small business & wanted to learn HTML & JS.

My particular issue is about how the logo image displays when the user inputs the URL.  The JS prompts for the logo URL after the user clicks the start button.  Then the script asks the user if they're happy with the image as displayed (i.e. shape & size).

When I load the site on IE11, the image displays as soon as the user enters the URL.  This way, they can see it immediately & decide if they're happy with it or not.  The problem is, when I run it on Google Chrome, the image doesn't load until the entirety of the invoice-generation program has run.  In other words, the image doesn't display until all the JS scripts that make up the program are executed.

Needless to say this limits my users to one attempt at displaying their logo since they don't see it on-screen until after the program is over.  Why does it display immediately in IE 11 but not Chrome, and how can I get it to display immediately in Chrome (if possible)?

The link to the page is [Generate Invoice](http://notesinyourmouth.com/generate-your-e-mailable-html-invoice/)

Here is the JS code that prompts for the image, displays it and re-sizes it as the user likes.

```
var url = prompt("Enter the URL for a picture of your logo:");

// create the IMG element to display the logo
var image = document.createElement("IMG");

// assign the user-input url to the variable holding the IMG element
image.src=url;

// Create a variable to assign the DIV to (by ID)
var imageLogo = document.getElementById("addLogoAndMessage");

// Clear out the DIV (i.e. make the button go away)
imageLogo.innerHTML = "";

// Append the image to the variable associated with the DIV
imageLogo.appendChild(image);

// custom width for CE logo is 220px
var logoWidth = prompt("Set a width for your logo.");
var logoWidth1 = logoWidth + "px";
imageLogo.appendChild(image).style.width = logoWidth1;

// custom height for CE logo is 200px
var logoHeight = prompt("Set a height for your logo. To maintain aspect ratio, just hit Enter.");
var logoHeight1 = logoHeight + "px";
if (logoHeight == "" || logoHeight == "undefined") {
    imageLogo.appendChild(image).style.height = "auto";
} else {
    imageLogo.appendChild(image).style.height = logoHeight1; 
}

var sizeOK = prompt("Are you happy with the shape and size of your logo (y/n)?");

while (sizeOK != "n" && sizeOK != "y") {
  sizeOK = prompt("Are you happy with the shape and size of your logo (y/n)?");
}

while (sizeOK == "n") {
  var logoWidth = prompt("Set a new width for your logo.");
  var logoWidth1 = logoWidth + "px";
  imageLogo.appendChild(image).style.width = logoWidth1;

  var logoHeight = prompt("Set a new height for your logo. To maintain aspect ratio, just hit Enter.");
  var logoHeight1 = logoHeight + "px";
  if (logoHeight == "" || logoHeight == "undefined") {
      imageLogo.appendChild(image).style.height = "auto";
  } else {
      imageLogo.appendChild(image).style.height = logoHeight1; 
  }

  // Ask after every width,height set so user can stop when they like the image
  sizeOK = prompt("If you're still not happy with your logo, enter 'n'. Otherwise, just hit Enter.");
}
```

Thank you for any thoughts or input.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Chrome waits for the image to finish loading before it performs a document reflow ( = before it updates the layout). Because the JavaScript is executed much faster than the image could have possibly loaded, you won't see the image until the JS has finished.

You could try attaching an `onload` event to the image that fires when it has finished loading. So, use

```
image.onload = imageHasLoaded;
image.src = url;
```

And then place the rest of the code within a seperate function

```
function imageHasLoaded() {
    //the rest of your code, to be executed once the image is displayed
}
```

Hope that helps!